# Solving $y''+2y'+2y=e^{-x}\sin(x)$ using variation of parameters.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

I am stuck on the following differential equation. Here is where I got to.
We first solve the homogeneous equation.
\begin{align*}
&y^{\prime\prime} + 2y^{\prime} + 2y = 0\Longrightarrow r^2+2r+2=0 \Longrightarrow \sqrt{D} = \sqrt{2^2-4\cdot1\cdot2} = \pm2i \Longrightarrow\\
&r = \frac{-2\pm2i}{2}=-1\pm i \Longrightarrow y = Ae^{-x}\cos(x)+Be^{-x}\sin(x)
\end{align*}
Now I vary the parameter: $y(x)=A(x)e^{-x}\cos(x)+B(x)e^{-x}\sin(x)$. But from here I have no idea how to plug the non-homogeneous equation. Do I need to use a 'wronskian' as noted in my book or simply take derivatives?

Comment: Assume solution of the form $y(x)=(Ax+B)e^{-x} \cos(x)+(Cx+D)e^{-x} \sin(x)$, then compute first and second derivative of the $y(x)$ and insert it in the given differential equation. Compare the coefficients of $\exp^-x \cos(x)$ and $\exp^-x \sin(x)$ on the both sides of equation, you will particular solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the `Undetermined Coefficients`, you should take few steps ahead just to find the proper particular solution $y_p$. It seems to me that you are walking on this railway. But, if you are interested in doing the `Variation of Parameters` so use the `Wronskian` as guessed. So, find the wronskian of $$y_1=e^{-x}\sin(x), ~y_2=e^{-x}\cos(x)$$ which is $W=-e^{-2x}(\neq 0)$ and for the rest use the formal relevant formulas: $$y_p=u_1y_1+u_2y_2$$ where $$u_1=\int\frac{-y_2\times e^{-x}\sin(x)}{W}dx, ~~u_2=\int\frac{y_1\times e^{-x}\sin(x)}{W}dx$$

Comment: The "$\times$" symbol mean "usual product"?

Comment: Yes that is right. Sorry if I made a trouble.

Answer (score 2):

The Wronskian is the way to go.

Otherwise you have to deal with a big mess of calculations.

Make sure that you check your answer and make sure you had the right signs in your formula for your coefficients.

Answer (score 2):

Let $u = Ae^{-x}\cos x + Be^{-x}\sin x$

We know that $u'' + 2u' + 2u = 0$

Suppose $y = xu$

Then

$y' = u + xu'\\
y'' = 2u' + xu''$

$y'' + 2y' + 2y = 2u' + 2u + x(u'' + 2u' + 2u) = e^{-x}\sin x\\
2(u'+u) = e^{-x}\sin x\\
u' = -Ae^{-x}\cos x  - Ae^{-x}\sin x  - Be^{-x}\sin x + Be^{-x}\cos x\\
2(u'+u) =  - 2Ae^{-x}\sin x +2Be^{-x}\cos x = e^{-x}\sin x \\
B = 0, A = -\frac 12 $

$y = C_1e^{-x}\cos x + C_2e^{-x}\sin x - \frac 12 e^{-x}\cos x$